# Deployment to Google App Engine Flexible is failing from Intellij

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have an Application on Spring Boot that I am want to deploy to my GAE Flexible project.

I am using Google Cloud Tool's latest version for deployment using the Google Cloud Plugin for Intellij. But the deployment is failing with the following exception:

```
Deploying '[2017-05-23 19:22:53] Maven build: backend_flexible. Project: healthy-dragon-168416. Version: 1'...
Created temporary staging directory: C:\Users\Digvijay\AppData\Local\Temp\gae-staging-healthy-dragon-1684162
You are about to deploy the following services:
 - healthy-dragon-168416/default/1 (from [C:\Users\Digvijay\AppData\Local\Temp\gae-staging-healthy-dragon-1684162\app.yaml])
     Deploying to URL: [https://healthy-dragon-168416.appspot.com]

If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...
...done.

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Building and pushing image for service [default]
Started cloud build [fb9c1b45-37bd-44db-8a2c-e3d21ddccd66].
To see logs in the Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/fb9c1b45-37bd-44db-8a2c-e3d21ddccd66?project=healthy-dragon-168416
----------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT ------------------------------
starting build "fb9c1b45-37bd-44db-8a2c-e3d21ddccd66"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://staging.healthy-dragon-168416.appspot.com/asia.gcr.io/healthy-dragon-168416/appengine/default.1:latest#1495547617343338
Copying gs://staging.healthy-dragon-168416.appspot.com/asia.gcr.io/healthy-dragon-168416/appengine/default.1:latest#1495547617343338...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/ 14.7 MiB]                                                
/ [0 files][264.0 KiB/ 14.7 MiB]                                                
-
- [0 files][  4.1 MiB/ 14.7 MiB]                                                
\
\ [1 files][ 14.7 MiB/ 14.7 MiB]                                                

Operation completed over 1 objects/14.7 MiB.                                     
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  17.42MB


Step 1/2 : FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty
latest: Pulling from google_appengine/jetty
Digest: sha256:5c3886bb6ad2c7800df4f4c5ea08b96b9696c93b1cbe680e411f0d684c997183
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty:latest
 ---> 2903b2805f30
Step 2/2 : ADD target.war $JETTY_BASE/webapps/root.war
 ---> e8b1c947eb72
Removing intermediate container 596e22679487
Successfully built e8b1c947eb72
Successfully tagged asia.gcr.io/healthy-dragon-168416/appengine/default.1:latest
PUSH
Pushing asia.gcr.io/healthy-dragon-168416/appengine/default.1:latest
The push refers to a repository [asia.gcr.io/healthy-dragon-168416/appengine/default.1]
995181bdf30b: Preparing
e5f61ed28c2e: Preparing
5f62410a1ff2: Preparing
48fda9d28da8: Preparing
a387774c7e67: Preparing
6fff2d1f2112: Preparing
2f65f91183d8: Preparing
a1375b417df0: Preparing
f029db0c96f4: Preparing
5c269b80652e: Preparing
52e854e7e519: Preparing
741cffb17349: Preparing
f84d6cd2c591: Preparing
eb2705dec5a9: Preparing
d26cbf1738a5: Preparing
6fff2d1f2112: Waiting
2f65f91183d8: Waiting
a1375b417df0: Waiting
f029db0c96f4: Waiting
5c269b80652e: Waiting
52e854e7e519: Waiting
741cffb17349: Waiting
f84d6cd2c591: Waiting
eb2705dec5a9: Waiting
d26cbf1738a5: Waiting
a387774c7e67: Layer already exists
e5f61ed28c2e: Layer already exists
5f62410a1ff2: Layer already exists
48fda9d28da8: Layer already exists
2f65f91183d8: Layer already exists
a1375b417df0: Layer already exists
6fff2d1f2112: Layer already exists
f029db0c96f4: Layer already exists
5c269b80652e: Layer already exists
52e854e7e519: Layer already exists
741cffb17349: Layer already exists
f84d6cd2c591: Layer already exists
d26cbf1738a5: Layer already exists
eb2705dec5a9: Layer already exists
995181bdf30b: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:041f18c29d722d7fc66b033375ce002fbac5e013498cd2e96c3d4154c9b7220d size: 3462
DONE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default]...
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
Caused by: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1442)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
2017-05-23 13:56:02.822:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@d8355a8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2017-05-23 13:56:02.822:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @9704ms
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@3ffc5af1 - STARTED
 += qtp1818402158{STARTED,10<=10<=200,i=7,q=0} - STARTED
 |   +- 16 qtp1818402158-16 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 20 qtp1818402158-20-acceptor-0@589c2f1c-ServerConnector@d8355a8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
 |   +- 18 qtp1818402158-18 RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 |   +- 11 qtp1818402158-11 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 12 qtp1818402158-12-lowPrioritySelector BLOCKED @ org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$SelectorProducer.produce(ManagedSelector.java:244) prio=1
 |   +- 13 qtp1818402158-13 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 19 qtp1818402158-19 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 14 qtp1818402158-14 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 15 qtp1818402158-15 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- 17 qtp1818402158-17 TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) IDLE
 |   +- jobs
 += org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@17ed40e0 - STARTED
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection@175c2241[org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@5bf0d49[o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@520a3426{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}{/root.war}], org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler@5b7a5baa] - STARTED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@5bf0d49[o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@520a3426{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}{/root.war}] - STARTED
 |   |   +~ o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@520a3426{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}{/root.war} - FAILED
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler@5b7a5baa - STARTED
 +- [org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration, org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration]
 += org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager@776aec5c - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider@1d296da - STARTED
 += ServerConnector@d8355a8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@3ffc5af1 - STARTED
 |   +~ qtp1818402158{STARTED,10<=10<=200,i=7,q=0} - STARTED
 |   +~ org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler@17ed40e0 - STARTED
 |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@7c7a06ec
 |   += HttpConnectionFactory@4de8b406[HTTP/1.1] - STARTED
 |   |   +- HttpConfiguration@75d4a5c2{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:443,[ForwardedRequestCustomizer@557caf28]}
 |   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector$ServerConnectorManager@408d971b - STARTED
 |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector@6c6cb480 id=0 keys=0 selected=0 id=0
 |   |       +- sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@411e07b3 keys=0
 |   +- sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080]
 |   +- qtp1818402158-20-acceptor-0@589c2f1c-ServerConnector@d8355a8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
 += org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler@292b08d6 - STARTED
 +- {file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar=org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@1a04f701, file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar=org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@1a04f701}
 +- {file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar=org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@1a04f701, file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar=org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@1a04f701}
 +- {file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar=[jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/c-1_0-rt.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/scriptfree.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/fmt-1_0-rt.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/sql-1_0-rt.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/c-1_1.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/permittedTaglibs.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/x-1_0-rt.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/fmt.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/sql.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/x.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/c.tld, jar:file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/META-INF/fn.tld], file:///opt/jetty-home/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar=[]}
 |
 +> startJarLoader@4bf558aa
     +- file:/var/lib/jetty/resources/
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-http-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-server-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-xml-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-util-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-io-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-jndi-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jndi/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-security-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-servlet-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-webapp-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-plus-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-annotations-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/annotations/asm-5.1.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/annotations/asm-commons-5.1.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.ecj-4.4.2.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.5.9.1.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-8.5.9.1.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/jetty-deploy-9.4.3.v20170317.jar
     +- file:/opt/jetty-home/lib/setuid/jetty-setuid-java-1.0.3.jar
     +- file:/var/lib/jetty/lib/gcp/jetty9-base-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
     +- sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
2017-05-23 13:56:02.866:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Available Context
    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.jetty9.DeploymentCheck.lifeCycleStarted(DeploymentCheck.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setStarted(AbstractLifeCycle.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Available Context
    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.jetty9.DeploymentCheck.lifeCycleStarted(DeploymentCheck.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setStarted(AbstractLifeCycle.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    ... 7 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Available Context
    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.jetty9.DeploymentCheck.lifeCycleStarted(DeploymentCheck.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.setStarted(AbstractLifeCycle.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1438)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1437)
    ... 7 more

Usage: java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar $JETTY_HOME/start.jar --help  # for more information

Failed to deploy '[2017-05-23 19:22:53] Maven build: backend_flexible. Project: healthy-dragon-168416. Version: 1': Deployment failed with exit code: 1
Please make sure that you are using the latest version of the Google Cloud SDK.
Run ''gcloud components update'' to update the SDK. (See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update.)
```

And, here is the deployment window I am presented with just before deploying:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it failed while trying to change your new version to the default service.  (And deleting your old version in the process).

There are a few things you can do to see if it is a problem with your code, or if its simply barfing on promoting your version.

1. You could try to increment the version number to 2, so that it isn't overriding the previous version.
2. You could try to manually stop/delete the version yourself in web console or using gcloud.
3. Set the version number higher, and uncheck the "promote this version" box.

If it has nothing to do with the promotion of your service, my best guess is that you're missing something in pom.xml/gradle that has to do with:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:183)`

And... I just realized it might be a problem with your app.yaml, specifically what you set as the `runtime : ???`.  If you set the runtime to "java" it should be using java8/jetty 9 runtime which runs servlet 3.1.

Comment: Actually, it does use servlet 3.1.... see: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml